# Understanding assignment of functions to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi everybody first time posting here.

So I am trying to understand something, I will post the code here too, but if you want to check out the source, its this " https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/spencer-sandbox/2/5?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661   "

Which is an exercise from codeacademy....

So there is `bob.setAge = setAge;` , why didn't it make it so `bob.setAge= newAge;` ??
here is the code .

```
var setAge = function (newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};
// now we make bob
var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;
bob.setAge = setAge;

// make susan here, and first give her an age of 25
var susan = new Object();
susan.age=25;
susan.setAge = setAge;


// here, update Susan's age to 35 using the method

susan.setAge(35);
```

Comment: `setAge` is a function ... later you can call it `bob.setAge(30)`.

Comment: bob.setAge= setAge define the setAge method of the object to be the function setAge, after that the method could be call and a value passed as parameter.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed - the question was very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this exercise is trying to teach you the fundamentals of object oriented programming in JavaScript without the syntactic sugar.

More simply stated, they are making a `person` and that `person` can have a set of attributes that describe them, and a set of actions they can do.

You've created this function here called `setAge`

```
var setAge = function (newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};
```

It'll set the age of an `this` to `newAge`. But the question here is what is `this`? The answer is that it depends, which is why you can reuse this function.

So when you "make bob"

```
// now we make bob
var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;
bob.setAge = setAge;
```

What you're doing is saying that `bob` has an action he can do called `setAge`, and this action is equivalent to the function we defined earlier called `setAge`. Also in this context `this` is refers to `bob`.

So when you do something like `bob.setAge(20)` then `bob.age`, represented by `this.age` will be changed from `30` to `20`.

Does that make sense?

Also in your link there is this quote

> Great! Now we can take advantage of the fact that the method setAge is not limited to a single object bob

Whether it's bob or susan, you can always use the same `setAge` function you defined above if you assign it to the object.

Comment: Yes i understand now. thanks a lot.... trying to learn java script can be confusing sometimes but the fast answer was really appreciated thanks again <3

Comment: Yeah no problem. Glad I was able to get an answer in before they closed it. They can be pretty unfriendly to new programmers here :/

Comment: im new here, i don't even know why they closed it :o. like i just made my account 10 minutes ago and then added my question.

Comment: @Munkiuke the problem was that you wrote `trying to understand how this works in javascript` which isn't a very descriptive title. I edited it to make it more clear, but it seems like I was too late. Next time just try to have your title be more specific.

Comment: ohhhhhh alright i understand now. thanks, i will try to be clear in the title next time. what does this ( on hold ) mean ?

Comment: @Munkiuke Here's a link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question. Also I'd appreciate if you press the checkmark to accept my answer.